# Terminology: customary name of graph "smoothing"

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

The Wikipedia page on *graph homeomorphism* describes an opposite operation of edge subdivision that it calls [*smoothing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_(graph_theory)#Subdivision_and_smoothing).

What is the customary name of this operation in mathematics?  Is there a name for the graph obtained by performing "smoothing" repeatedly as many times as possible?

I have seen the term *subdivision* used in many places, but I have not seen the term *smoothing* anywhere else than on Wikipedia.

In particular, I am looking for a good name to use in a software package for the following operation: perform smoothing as many times as possible (thus removing all degree-2 vertices).  Is *smoothen* a reasonable name for this operation, that would feel natural to a mathematician?

Comment: Suppression is the word, well, the only one I've ever heard.

Comment: @Countingstuff Searching along those lines, I also found the term [*topological minor*](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2014-15/2term/ma006b/07%20minors.pdf). Is there a separate term for the unique smallest possible topological minor of a graph. I mean this allowing self-loops and multi-edges, i.e. for a cycle graph we'd get a single vertex graph with a self-loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia also calls it [edge contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_contraction). There is a very similar [MSE question 197972](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197972) removing degree-2 vertices from a graph.

Comment: Edge contraction is a more general term; you can only "smooth" out a vertex of degree $2$ (which is equivalent to contracting one of its edges), but by contracting other edges you can get other behavior, too.

Comment: You are correct. Edge contraction is a more general term.